# Max function is a metric?

Tags: functions, absolute-value

I was wondering if the max function is a metric or if, in particular, $\max(|x  + y|, 1)$ is equal or less than $\max(|x|, 1) + \max(|y|, 1)$ with $x$ and $y$ belonging to $R$.

Comment: What is $max(n)$?

Comment: $|x + y| \le |x| + |y|$ by the triangle inequality. In a metric space.

Comment: Max is taken over a set. What is the meaning of max(|x|)?

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake. Now it seems more meaningful

Comment: I see the edit.  This is clearly not linear, right?  $max(.75+.75,1)≠max(.75,1)+max(.75,1)$.

Comment: By $R$, do you mean the set of all real numbers? That is usually notated $\mathbb{R}$, sometimes $\textbf{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof by cases:

Case 1: If $|x+y|\geq 1$, then:

$\max(|x+y|, 1)=|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|\leq\max(|x|, 1)+\max(|y|, 1)$

Case 2: $|x+y|<1$, then:

$\max(|x+y|, 1)=1<1+1\leq\max(|x|, 1)+\max(|y|, 1)$

Comment: Ok thanks. It is clear now!